# Race condition and mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, race-condition

I have 2 questions regarding to threads, one is about race condition and the other is about mutex.
So the first question :
I've read about race condition in wikipedia page :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

And in the example of race condition between 2 threads this is shown :
http://i60.tinypic.com/2vrtuz4.png[

Now so far I believed that threads works parallel to each other, but judging from this picture it's seems that I interpreted on how actions done by the computer wrong.
From this picture only 1 action is done at a time, and although the threads gets switched from time to time and the other thread gets to do some actions this is still 1 action at a time done by the computer. Is it really like this ? There's no "real" parallel computing, just 1 action done at a time in a very fast rate which gives the illusion of parallel computing ?

This leads me to my second question about mutex.
I've read that if threads read/write to the same memory we need some sort of synchronization mechanism. I've read the normal data types won't do and we need a mutex.
Let's take for example the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

bool lock = false;

void increment(void*);
void decrement(void*);

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    HANDLE hIncrement = (HANDLE)_beginthread(increment, 0, (void*)&n);
    HANDLE hDecrement = (HANDLE)_beginthread(decrement, 0, (void*)&n);
    WaitForSingleObject(hIncrement, 1000 * 500);
    WaitForSingleObject(hDecrement, 1000 * 500);
    return 0;
}

void increment(void *p)
{
    int *n = p;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        while (lock)
       {

       }
       lock = true;
       (*n)++;
       lock = false;
    }
}

void decrement(void *p)
{
    int *n = p;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        while (lock)
       {

       }
       lock = true;
       (*n)--;
       lock = false;
    }
}
```

Now in my example here, I use bool lock as my synchronization mechanism to avoid a race condition between the 2 threads over the memory space pointed by pointer n.
Now what I did here won't obviously work because although I avoided a race condition over the memory space pointed by pointer n between the 2 threads a new race condition over bool lock variable may occur.

Let's consider the following sequence of events (A = increment thread, B = decrement thread) :

- A gets out of the while loop since lock is false
- A gets to set lock to true
- B waits in the while loop because lock is set to true
- A increment the value pointed by n
- A sets lock to false
- A gets to the while loop
- A gets out of the while loop since lock is false
- B gets out of the while loop since lock is false
- A sets lock to true
- B sets lock to true

and from here we get an unexpected behavior of 2 un-synchronized threads because the **bool lock is not race condition proof**.

Ok, so far this is my understanding and the solution to our problem above we need a mutex.
I'm fine with that, a data type that will magically be condition race proof.
I just don't understand how with mutex type it won't happen where as with every other type it will and here lies my problem, I want to understand why mutex and how this is happening.

Comment: You *can* have multiple threads running simultaneously on a multiprocessor system.

Comment: You can't use SO to learn a new expertise like threading. I suggest you find a good site and tutorial and start studying. Your question shows that you have absolutely no idea what threading is about or how it works.

Comment: I interpret that as a perfectly valid question, albeit with a lot of extra exposition around it that's probably a result of being slightly confused about an unfamiliar context (I notice the same tendency in my own questions). So, what I think @Omlis532 is after is the question: "How can a threadsafe mutex type exist, when all basic types are not threadsafe?"

Comment: @CarloWood I didn't said what I said was necessarily correct, I said that this is my understanding of it, that's why I'm coming here and asking my questions regarding to the topic trying to understand more. Saying to me you don't understand it go to the internet and read about it (although I did) is not helpful in anyway.

Comment: @Medo42 that's correct regarding to my second question :)

Comment: You may want to read up on [Interlocked Compare/Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583(v=vs.110).aspx) and related operations.

Comment: @Omlis532 The point of mutual exclusion (mutex) is that it make only one thread at a time execute a piece of code, while other threads that wants to acquire the mutex gets suspended, and will wait until the mutex is released again. That way you can ensure only one thread at at time runs when the variables are accessed (as long as all code that accesses those variables are also guarded by the same mutex). THe implementation of a mutex can do this since it uses hardware and operating system specific features designed to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your first question: Whether or not there are actually several different threads running at once, or whether it is just implemented as as fast switching, is a matter of your hardware. Typical PCs these days have several cores (often with more than one thread each), so you have to assume that things actually DO happen at the same time.

But even if you have only a single-core system, things are not quite so easy. This is because the compiler is usually allowed to re-order instructions in order to optimize code. It can also e.g. choose to cache a variable in a CPU register instead of loading it from memory every time you access it, and it also doesn't have to write it back to memory every time you write to that variable. The compiler is allowed to do that as long as the result is the same AS IF it had run your original code in its original order - as long as nobody else is looking closely at what's actually going on, such as a different thread.

And once you actually do have different cores, consider that they all have their own CPU registers and even their own cache. Even if a thread on one core wrote to a certain variable, as long as that core doesn't write its cache back to the shared memory a different core won't see that change.

In short, you have to be very careful in making any assumptions about what happens when two threads access variables at the same time, especially in C/C++. The interactions can be so surprising that I'd say, to stay on the safe side, you should make sure that there are no race conditions in your code, e.g. by always using mutexes for accessing memory that is shared between threads.

Which is where we can neatly segway into the second question: What's so special about mutexes, and how can they work if all basic data types are not threadsafe?

The thing about mutexes is that they are implemented with a lot of knowledge about the system for which they are being used (hardware and operating system), and with either the direct help or a deep knowledge of the compiler itself.

The C language does not give you direct access to all the capabilities of your hardware and operating system, because platforms can be very different from each other. Instead, C focuses on providing a level of abstraction that allows you to compile the same code for many different platforms. The different "basic" data types are just something that the C standard came up with as a set of data types which can in some way be supported on almost any platform - but the actual hardware that your program will be compiled for is usually not limited to those types and operations.

In other word, not everything that you can do with your PC can be expressed in terms of C's ints, bytes, assignments, arithmetic operators and so on. For example, PCs often calculate with 80-bit floating point types which are usually not mapped directly to a C floating point type at all. More to the point of our topic, there are also CPU instructions that influence how multiple CPU cores will work together. Additionally, if you know the CPU, you often know a few things about the behaviour of the basic types that the C standard doesn't guarantee (for example, whether loads and stores to 32-bit integers are atomic). With that extra knowledge, it can become possible to implement mutexes *for that particular platform*, and it will often require code that is e.g. written directly in assembly language, because the necessary features are not available in plain C.

Comment: Do you think you could link me to a good tutorial using mutex and threads ? I'm creating threads using _beginthread and type casting it to an HANDLE, so I've looked online but I couldn't find someone that uses _beginthread type casting it to an HANDLE and using mutex so I don't think what posted online applies to my code. Would be much appreciated !

Comment: I have never done multithreading with that API, but there is MSDN documentation about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/y6h8hye8.aspx. In the example program there, they use the functions `CreateMutex`, `WaitForSingleObject` and `ReleaseMutex`. You should be aware though that those mutexes are cross-process, which is often more than you want/need.

Comment: means that the thread created by the API are threads in different cores or .. ?

Comment: Sorry, but please read up on what a process is and what a thread is. What I meant to say is that the mutexes in that API can be used to synchronize multiple processes, not just multiple threads. This has nothing at all to do with CPU cores.